# Bootstrap menu won't stay open on most mobile devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a website that uses bootstrap heavily for layout and responsiveness.  I am using bootstrap 4.1.1 with jquery 3.3.1.   I have just revamped a site and upgraded versions of the modules I'm using.

Everything works great except on most mobile device my hamburger menu will not stay open.  It opens and immediately closes before you can click an option.  On a PC it everything works as expected.

I only have a few handsets to test on but I get this behavior on Android and iOS... funny enough on Android it doesn't work on a Pixel 2 XL using Chrome but it works on a Nexus 6 with Chrome.

This behavior is in both jquery 3.2.x and the latest version, 3.3.1.  I develop in Visual Studio so the menu is created with defaults that I edited down and when compared to bootstraps own examples I'm almost identical... And it doesn't fix it when I change to make up the differences.

I can find similar issues online but every one I've read deals with someone modifying the behaviors of script or adding classes they shouldn't... I haven't done that and where I have (such as "fixed-top") I've tried removing them and still get the same results.  (I am not modifying javascript).  Also I did not build the changes over top of the old site, I created a site from scratch and rewrote it.

I do make 1 change in class, however this worked fine on the old version of the site with older versions of jquery and bootstrap.

```
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(#92A8B7, #285270);
}
```

I have posted my menu HTML below... This is available publicly so I can provide a URL to the actual site that has the problem... I am just not 100% sure of policy on posting links in questions.

Can someone assist in determining what may be causing the menu to immediately close as soon as it's opened?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="/image/Logo_site_small.png" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class='nav-link <%=IsSelected("default")%>' href="/" >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%=IsSelected("media")%>" href="/media">Press / Media</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%=IsSelected("events")%>" href="/events">Events</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%=IsSelected("galleries")%>" href="/galleries">Photos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%=IsSelected("buy")%>" href="/linkit.ashx?code=buyunit5comix" target="_blank">Buy</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%=IsSelected("About")%>" href="/about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%=IsSelected("contact")%>" href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <li><a href="/linkit.ashx?code=u5facebook" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="/image/facebook-e1417900370137.png" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/linkit.ashx?code=u5insta" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="/image/INSTAGRAM-e1417900651282.png" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="/linkit.ashx?code=u5twitter" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="/image/twitter-e1417900317929.png" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>

                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Can you post the url? There’s nothing wrong with posting links.

Comment: Sure, www.unit5comic.com

Comment: I tested it on an iPhone and a Samsung Gallaxy and the menu stays open.

Comment: Thanks @muecas.  Seems hit or miss... Not sure what's causing the behavior...  Something definitely not working across the spectrum.  With your 2 devices that gives me a total of 3 good, 3 bad.  Not a great ratio.